# Can't examine actual, working, valid variables in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: json, visual-studio

```
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.Count; i++) {

    try {

        var record = jsonData[i];
        
        Console.WriteLine(record["campaign_id"].ToString());
        // writes "1883285" to console

        for (int j = 0; j < record["groups"].Count; j++) {
            Console.WriteLine(record["groups"].Count);
            // writes "1" to console
        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.Write(ex);
    }

}
```

The above code works flawlessly, and produces all the results I need, however when I breakpoint it, and step through with the debugger to examine `record`:

```
record["campaign_id"].ToString()
error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

record["groups"].Count
error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'
```

Even though the outer (i) loop properly loops 12 times, once for each of the 12 objects it has, and the inner (j) loop executes once, and prints "1" on the console.

What am I doing wrong (if anything, if perhaps this is expected behaviour).

Here is the json it's working through.  [This example, just the first of the 12 campaigns, for brevity.]

```
[
  {
    "campaign_id": 1883285,
    "name": "Foundational Cybersecurity Training 2",
    "groups": [
      {
        "group_id": 4359130,
        "name": "Cybersecurity Awareness Foundations 2"
      }
    ],
    "status": "In Progress",
    "content": [
      {
        "store_purchase_id": 5882216,
        "content_type": "Store Purchase",
        "name": "2023 Your Role: Internet Security and You",
        "description": "This module helps the average user become familiar with a variety of today’s common cyber...",
        "type": "Training Module",
        "duration": 17,
        "retired": false,
        "retirement_date": null,
        "publish_date": "2022-08-30T17:56:49.000Z",
        "publisher": "KnowBe4",
        "purchase_date": "2023-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "policy_url": null
      },
      {
        "store_purchase_id": 5882223,
        "content_type": "Store Purchase",
        "name": "2023 Common Threats",
        "description": "In this module, Kevin Mitnick explains some of the latest ways that cybercriminals are targeting...",
        "type": "Training Module",
        "duration": 17,
        "retired": false,
        "retirement_date": null,
        "publish_date": "2022-08-30T12:40:04.000Z",
        "publisher": "KnowBe4",
        "purchase_date": "2023-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "policy_url": null
      },
      {
        "store_purchase_id": 5882226,
        "content_type": "Store Purchase",
        "name": "2023 Social Engineering Red Flags",
        "description": "Social engineering is one of the main tricks cybercriminals use to get people to take actions...",
        "type": "Training Module",
        "duration": 15,
        "retired": false,
        "retirement_date": null,
        "publish_date": "2022-09-30T21:40:06.000Z",
        "publisher": "KnowBe4",
        "purchase_date": "2023-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
        "policy_url": null
      }
    ],
    "duration_type": "Relative End Date",
    "start_date": "2023-10-09T14:00:00.000Z",
    "end_date": null,
    "relative_duration": "1 months",
    "auto_enroll": true,
    "allow_multiple_enrollments": false,
    "completion_percentage": 64
  },
  {}, ... 11 more campaigns
]
```

Comment: "groups" is an array, so it could contain more than one object, even though in the json it never actually does.  It's always ONE object.  But I need the code to be ready to accommodate more if it ever comes up.